# How to use airbnb style guide with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, eslint

I would like to use the airbnb style guide with my NextJS 13.4.9 project. When creating an NextJS app, one is asked about enable ESlint. I imagine saying "yes" to this is the recommended way. This allows one to `npm run lint` or `npx next lint`.

[This](https://www.lukinotes.com/2022/01/setting-up-nextjs-project-with-eslint-typescript-airbnb.html) simple guide explains how to install airbnb style guide, but it gives conflict with the latest version of NextJS. See below.

According to the [NextJS doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#eslint-config) on ESLint, `eslint-config-next` includes

- eslint-plugin-react
- eslint-plugin-react-hooks
- eslint-plugin-next

So it would be temping to uninstall the `eslint-config-next` package, and then install these packages myself to get versions that don't conflict.

**Question**

If I do this, will I then lose some NextJS specific linting?

Or what is the recommended way to add airbnb style guide to the `next lint`?

```
$ npm install -D eslint-config-airbnb 

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: test@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-react-hooks@5.0.0-canary-7118f5dd7-20230705
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
npm ERR!   eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"5.0.0-canary-7118f5dd7-20230705" from eslint-config-next@13.4.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm ERR!     eslint-config-next@"13.4.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev eslint-config-airbnb@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"^4.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@19.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Try installing them one at a time so see which is throwing the error?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have now updated OP, where I just install one.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the eslint packages from NextJS, and then install them again solved dependency problem.

The ones that came with NextJS are not official versions, so that must be why the conflict arises.

Answer (score -1):

you need to peerDependency install first

you can check peerDependencies by code on below

```bash
$ npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies
{
  eslint: '^7.32.0 || ^8.2.0',
  'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.25.3',
  'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^6.5.1',
  'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.28.0',
  'eslint-plugin-react-hooks': '^4.3.0'
}
```

install cli

```bash
 yarn add -D eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks
```

I hope my answer helps you